# Need different digits inserted by condition in Paste function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the space function to insert different amounts of 0s based on the number of digits in the value.

```
STATE_FIPS   COUNTY_FIPS
1            5
1            15
1            100
```

When I do it right now, I am getting this:

```
FIPS
15
115
1100
```

but I am trying to get this:

```
FIPS
1005
1015
1100
```

I am using this code but I'm assuming it is incomplete.

```
fips$fips_complete <- paste(fips$State.FIPS.Code, fips$County.FIPS.Code)
```

Is it possible to get the aforementioned result?

Comment: Your code uses different variable names than what you show in the example data. I assumed it was renamed at some point and just based my answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `str_pad()`.

```r
fips <- data.frame(STATE_FIPS = c("1", "1", "1"),
                   COUNTY_FIPS = c("5", "15", "100"),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(stringr)

fips$fips_complete <- paste0(fips$STATE_FIPS, str_pad(fips$COUNTY_FIPS, 3, "left", "0"))

> fips
  STATE_FIPS COUNTY_FIPS fips_complete
1          1           5          1005
2          1          15          1015
3          1         100          1100
```

You can also convert to numeric and do some math.

```r
fips$fips_complete2 <- as.character(as.numeric(fips$STATE_FIPS) * 1000 + as.numeric(fips$COUNTY_FIPS))

> fips
  STATE_FIPS COUNTY_FIPS fips_complete fips_complete2
1          1           5          1005           1005
2          1          15          1015           1015
3          1         100          1100           1100
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could try:

```
df$fips_complete <- paste0(
  df$STATE_FIPS,
  sprintf("%03d", df$COUNTY_FIPS)
)
```

**Output**

```
  STATE_FIPS COUNTY_FIPS fips_complete
1          1           5          1005
2          1          15          1015
3          1         100          1100
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(STATE_FIPS = c(1, 1, 1), COUNTY_FIPS = c(5, 15, 
100), fips_complete = c("1005", "1015", "1100")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```